# Calculated Date after 3 years

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-server, calculated-column, calculated-column-formula

Can anyone please tell how to get the calculated date after 3 years from current date.
I have tried different combinations none is working

```
=TEXT(YEAR(Created)+3,"MM/DD/YYYY")
```

It returns 07/06/1905.But answer should be 6/23/2017

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following:

```
=DATE(YEAR(Created)+3,MONTH(Created),DAY(Created))
```